# Overflow on UI-sortable and knockout. Dragged element disappears

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a strange behavior by using UI-sortable and knockout: on dragging one "report item" to target, once the dragged element leaves the container "Reports", it can not be seen. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexkrush/wrHW5/3/). That happens when I'm adding

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

on the style .metro-section-reports. Without overflow it working fine.

Anyone could help me with the problem?

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wrHW5/7/

The dragged element is not able to leave the parent anymore because of the overflow setting. What I did was add the following in your sortable binding:

```
options: { helper: 'clone', appendTo: 'body' }
```

As is probably obvious, it generates a copy of the dragged element, appends it to the body, and uses that for dragging.

See http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper for more details

Comment: Thanks, but how I remove this copy of the dragged element, that is created during dragging. I've tried smth. like 
<div class="metro-section" data-bind="sortable: { data: tiles, options: { cancel: '.no-sort',  helper: 'clone', appendTo: 'body'},                                                                               update: function(e, ui) { console.log('s');}, but it doesn't work
                                                                            }">

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Why do you want to remove it and what did you try? Normally, I don't think you have to worry about removing it. jQuery will handle that. See http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper